# What happens to my Reputation Points when I delete my Account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I saw a link telling that I can delete my StackOverFlow Account. so My Question is what will be happens to my Earned Reputation Points and Badges ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? They won't exist as you account doesn't exist.

Comment: They get equally distributed to all StackExchange employees.

Comment: Perhaps they could be donated to young rappers without street cred? Or perhaps a "Bling for Badges" program?

Comment: You account is deleted, the questions and answers aren't.

Comment: Don't worry, your reputation points and badges will be recycled. We care a lot about the environment here!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `Community` user gets them, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: Can I haz ur reputation plz?!

Comment: I am not getting a proper answer... many of them are on the assumption base. whose comment should I consider.

Comment: None. They're *comments* for a reason. Look at the answers instead.

Comment: Why would you possibly care?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your rep gets assigned to the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user. Badges go

[image]

Comment: http://daybreakservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/poof1.jpg

Comment: That poof is going to come in very, very handy :) Thanks!

Comment: Does Community actually get the reputation?